# I am trying to make a grid where the objects in my grid appear in a box pattern instead of a line

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to do this on and off for months and I think I'm just lost on what my code is doing exactly. I've never posted a question here before so sorry if I have some formatting issues or didn't do something correctly. Here is my HTML/CSS code:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'characters/style.css' %}">

<style>
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 150px);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
        align-items: initial;
    }

    .grid-item {
        border: 5px solid #87b5ff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #1c57b5
    }


</style>

<div class="grid-container">
    {% if character_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for character in character_list %}
            <div class="grid-item">
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'characters:detail' character.id %}">
                        <img src={{character.stock.url}} width="100" height="100" class="center">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</div>
    {% else %}
        <p>No characters are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Here is what it currently looks like, I want it to be spread out more horizontally, with 4 icons per row
[image: current]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The unordered list (i.e. ul) is not necessary and the way you have it structured is going to cause issues. You are separating the li from its ul with a div for every grid-item. Remove the unordered list.
2. You have a five column grid and are expecting four items per row. That's not going to do what you want (unless you start controlling grid-cell spans which you are not trying to do).

Try something like this; where you see a number, replace that with your anchor and image tags:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 150px); /* notice 4 columns not five */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
  align-items: initial;
}

.grid-container > div {
  border: 5px solid #87b5ff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #1c57b5;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the unordered list was messing everything up, it looks much better now!